# NuGet doesn't show items in feed, but can list via console

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, teamcity, nuget-server

I recently upgraded to TeamCity 9, at first everything was okay. Then, for some unknown reason, I was unable to get a full list of available packages via the NuGet GUI. At first it appeared that all the portable class libraries where missing, then all of them went missing.

What I've tried:

- I've removed all old artifacts from TeamCity,
- I've deleted and reset TeamCity's cache
- I've restarted TeamCity and its NuGet v1 service
- I've rebuilt some basic class libries (PCL) with no dependencies.
- I've cleared NuGet cache in my Visual Studio options.
- I've ran VS as admin.

When I click on my TeamCity Feed in the package manager, it immediately returns no results with a very brief flash of "retrieving result".

Okay so the very odd thing is I can manually list (and install) my packages via the console:

```
PM> Get-Package -ListAvailable

Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                                                                                          
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                                                                                          
RobGeoLtd.Core                 1.0.2                Core Framework Portable Class Library                                                                                                              
RobGeoLtd.Measurement          0.1.36               Defines units of measurement and conversion methods between them                                                                                   


PM> Install-Package RobGeoLtd.Core
Installing 'RobGeoLtd.Core 1.0.2'.
Successfully installed 'RobGeoLtd.Core 1.0.2'.
Adding 'RobGeoLtd.Core 1.0.2' to Logger.
Successfully added 'RobGeoLtd.Core 1.0.2' to Logger.

PM>
```

So yeah, I'm at a loss. NuGet bug? I'm all up-to-date as far as I can tell. :/

Answer (score 4):

For anyone experiencing a similar issue:

I also tried all of the above. It turned out that my built packages were targeting .NET 4.5.2 and my project was targeting .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear to be a TeamCity issue. I reverted to a back up of the CI server running 8.1.4 and the old feed items have returned. I will attempt the upgrade again.

Update: Yup, its defiantly the upgrade from 8.1.4 to 9.0.3 that caused it. Will file a bug. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-40589